# Analysing a C# strings to different variables

Tags: c#, string

I have a string (for example - "123456789"),
and I need to cut the first 3 characters("123") and the last 4("6789") to different variables(a = the original string, b = the 3 chars, c = the 4 chars).
How can I do it (put the data in b + c)?

Comment: Check the `Substring()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string a = "123456789";
string b = a.Substring(0, 3);
string c = a.Substring(a.Length - 4);
string result = b + c; // 1236789
```

If your original string can have length less than 4, then

```
string b = a.Substring(0, Math.Min(a.Length, 3));
string c = a.Substring(a.Length - Math.Min(a.Length, 4));
string result = b + c; // will return "1231234" for "1234"
```

Or even more checks, if you don't want to capture same symbols in string `b` and `c`:

```
string b = a.Length >= 3 ? a.Substring(0,3) : a;
string c = a.Length >= 7 ? a.Substring(a.Length - 4) : "";
string result = b + c; // will return "123" for "1234"
```

And exotic solution with regular expressions (it will take groups only if there is enough symbols in original string, i.e. you should have at least 7 symbols for second group to be captured)

```
string result = Regex.Replace(a, "^(.{3}).*(.{4})$", "$1$2");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but remember to check it's length:

```
string original = "123456789";
string firstThree = original.Substring(0, original.Length >= 3 ? 3 : original.Length);
string lastFour = original.Substring(original.Length >= 4 ? original.Length -4: 0);
```

Here is a (less efficient but maybe more readable and less error-prone) LINQ approach:

```
firstThree = string.Join("", original.Take(3));
lastFour = string.Join("", original.Skip(original.Length - 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**String.Substring**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
string original = "123456789";
string a = original;
string b = original.Substring(0, 3);
string c = original.Substring(original.Length - 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) - the former to get parts of a string given and index and a length and the second for finding indexed of inner strings/characters.